# How do I configure my Android Emulator's Network Address Space?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-networking

I am attempting to change my Emulator's Network Address to 10.0.2.2 so that I can test it using PHP stored on my localhost. However, despite reading through all the Emulator documentation, I cannot figure out exactly where to alter the emulator's primary network address. Is there any easy way to configure my emulator to query my localhost?

Comment: Why do you need to change your emulator's network address? Your emulator and computer are on the same network. Simply use 10.0.2.2 to connect to the localhost on your computer..

Comment: I don't, I think I worded that incorrectly. How exactly do I use 10.0.2.2 to connect to the localhost on my computer through the emulator?

Comment: Use your code to connect to the address.